# Cloudkit suddenly unable to upload because "Couldn't get a signing certificate"

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Just today as I try to upload a CKAsset to cloudkit, I am returned the error

> <CKError 0x155128f0: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't get a signing certificate">

This was working perfectly before and was not throwing this error.

Does anyone know why this is happening or if it is a problem on Apple's side?

Comment: @malena Glad to hear I guess its just server issues that are out of our control?

Comment: I don't know , I need to check that bug report, people mentioned in another thread : 22064324

Comment: @malena ok please tell me what you find I want to release my app tomorrow and this bug is killing me

Comment: can't find that bug in the Apple bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem. I searched by the number but no results. Let me know if you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Im just going to assume its an issue on iclouds part because its working now and i didn't change anything

Comment: It is not working for me yet. I noticed that however if I run my app in the Xcode simulator then the cloudKit fetch works.

Comment: Okay let me know if you find a solution. I found that it would fix itself then 20 minutes later it would break again but it is working now

Comment: I wonder, I updated Xcode from 7.1 to 7.3 but i am sure I tested my app after I updated Xcode and it worked. I wonder if you had also made any updates?

Comment: Aaand now it's working. Thanks for the 5 hours of unannounced downtime, Apple!

Comment: Good to hear this is a bit worrisome but hopefully its a one time thing with the transition to iOS 10

Comment: Yup, cloudKit calls are now working. I can't believe they didn't announce that there would be some downtime. Can't really trust cloudKit. Next time i will look for alternatives.