# CloudKit "Couldn't get a signing certificate" on device only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cloudkit

`<CKError 0x13766b8a0: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't get a signing certificate">`

I'm getting this error on both production and development containers *only* on actual devices. The simulator is able to fetch records just fine. This is happening on development builds running through XCode, TestFlight builds, and the live production build on the AppStore.

All devices and simulators are logged into the same iCloud AppleID.

Steps taken so far on non-functioning devices (iPhone, iPad):

- Uninstall/reinstall app
- Sign out/sign in to iCloud on devices, then uninstall/reinstall
- Download directly from AppStore

From what i've been reading, it looks like this issue is often due to an Apple brainfart or something that seems to magically go away after a few days? I mean, come on. I'm trying to really give CloudKit a shot here. I haven't yet tried a different AppleID in case there is something up with my account.

Does anyone have any ideas, or is anyone else experiencing the same thing?

Cheers

UPDATE: Tried a different, completely fresh/new iCloud account. Same issue.

Comment: Seems you're not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419929/cloudkit-suddenly-unable-to-upload-because-couldnt-get-a-signing-certificate

Comment: I also have this issue (and still). In the simulator it works just fine. But not on the phone. But I experienced something very strange because when I turn off my WiFi on the ohone and try with mobile internet then it also works. When turning back on my WiFi it doesn't work. But my MacBook is also connected with the same wifi and the simulator works....

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand it's back up. Looks like it was just 5+ hours of unannounced downtime from Apple... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419929/cloudkit-suddenly-unable-to-upload-because-couldnt-get-a-signing-certificate) is at least one other person who experienced the same issue.